# Random spacing between social buttons?

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why I have a random space between the twitter and G+ buttons.
Here's an example: http://i951.photobucket.com/albums/ad356/osjoe2/Snip2.png

CSS:

```
   #share { margin:0 30px; }
   #share ul { margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0 0 5px 0; list-style:none; border-bottom:1px solid #eee }
   #share li { display:inline; vertical-align: top; }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="share">
    <ul>

    <li style="padding-bottom:5px">
    {exp:fbc:like
    href="{url_title_path="shout/comments"}"
    send="false"
    layout="button_count"
    width=""
    show_faces="false"
    action="like"
    colorscheme="light"
    font="arial"
    }
    </li>

    <li><g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone></li>

    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post a www.jsFiddle.com to show what you mean? Would be easier to work with than an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different social buttons, once dynamically added to your page, will have their own width and height attributes.

You should give a unique class to each `<li>` (such as `.social-facebook`, `.social-twitter`) and tweak their widths accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this didn't seem to have any effect at all. I even added the styles inline and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you leave your `<li>` as `display:inline`? Because you can't add width/height to inline elements. Try changing it to `display:inline-block`.

Comment: what about - if the count will have more digits (instead of 1, will be 555? I tried to override in all possible manners - it is not working - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

would be nice to see the whole html and css there from the 3 social buttons. Like this its hard to tell if its the twitter or the g+

Comment: I put all the code you see on a BLANK html document and it does the same thing, so it doesn't look like anything else is conflicting with it.